# In a Custom Renderer, when should SetValueFromRenderer be used?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The documentation here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Element$Xamarin.Forms.IElementController.SetValueFromRenderer/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/System.Object/

Simply states:

> Sets a value from a renderer without breaking the binding on a bound property.

The Setter invocation looks like this as well:

```
set { ((IElementController)this).SetValueFromRenderer(TheProperty, value); }
```

But I'm unclear on what that provides?  I'm looking through some code on github in Xamarin.Forms and I see this being used frequently so I wanted to get a better understanding of it's purpose and proper use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Eric's answer](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/112419/#Comment_112419). Basically you will want to use that to set your Xamarin Forms Control's property from the custom renderer instead of setting the Control's property directly. If your Control's property has a `OneWay` binding, setting it directly from the custom renderer could break that binding.

The same thing happens in a normal XF `ContentPage`. If I do the following, the binding gets overwritten with the second assignment:

```
Entry entry = new Entry();

entry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "EntryText"); //Binding is set and good

entry.Text = "blah"; //Binding is overwritten with my hard coded "blah" value
```

**Example**

Bad:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName) {
        Element.Text = "Overwritten";
    }
}
```

Good:

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName == Entry.TextProperty.PropertyName) {
        ((IElementController)Element).SetValueFromRenderer(Entry.TextProperty, "Overwritten");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer with the example of how it breaks!! Made it click.